Even after importing a self signed certificate from an Oracle database into the trust store, it is still not trusted
I have a simple Java application that opens a connection to an Oracle database. The Oracle database has a self signed certificate. I exported the self signed certificate from the Oracle wallet and imported it into the cacerts java trust store.
However when I run the program I am still seeing the error:
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|01|main|2024-09-19 10:35:54.501 CEST|TransportContext.java:352|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (
"throwable" : {
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Since its a self-signed cert there is no "valid certification path" but is it is in the trust store, my expectation is that it should be trusted and that this error should not occur.
Java Code
package org.ibm;


import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class OracleConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        //Create a custom TrustManager


        VerifyCertificate.verifyCert();
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=5500))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=your_db))(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN=\"\")))";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "sys");
        props.setProperty("password", "password");

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props)) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/home/pat/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.23-sem/bin/java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl  -classpath /home/pat/Projects/clients/blm/oracle-ssl/target/classes:/home/pat/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/19.8.0.0/ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar org.ibm.OracleConnection

I used this command to import the cert:
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -cacerts -alias myselfsignedcert -file server_cert.pem  -storepass changeit

➜  oracle-ssl git:(master) ✗ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/pat/.sdkman/candidates/java/current

I am baffled by this error frankly because all documentation says that if you import a self-signed certificate into the java truststore it should trust it.
openjdk 11.0.23 2024-04-16
IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition 11.0.23.0 (build 11.0.23+9)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM 11.0.23.0 (build openj9-0.44.0, JRE 11 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20240522_1104 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - b0699311c7
OMR      - 254af5a04
JCL      - 3d1045c3ea based on jdk-11.0.23+9)


Can you rerun with the following VM argument to check whether you see your imported certificate in the logs? -Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake It will also give you other information to detect the issue. It might be helpfull to paste the logs in your question

What I determined is that for some reason , perhaps the version of java I am using, it will simply not accept a self signed certificate, even if the self signed certificate is in the trust store. The only way I was able to get around this was to create my own root ca, sign the cert with the ca, then import the ca into the trust store. Then it worked
